Yup validation not working for multiple object fields with identical types in a schema
I'm using Yup for form validation in my React application. I have a schema where I need to validate multiple object fields independently. However, I'm encountering an issue where Yup validation only works for one object field at a time, even though the shapes of the objects are identical and share the same type
const comparisonTableSchema = object().shape({
  baseMonth: object().shape({
    _id: string().required('Please select a month'),
    name: string().required(),
  }),
  targetMonth: object().shape({
    _id: string().required('Please select a month'),
    name: string().required(),
  }),
  matrix: object().shape({
    _id: string().required('Please select a matrix'),
    name: string().required(),
  }),
  // Other fields...
});

The problem is that when I submit the form, Yup validation only shows errors for one object field at a time. If I fulfill the criteria for one field and submit again, then it shows errors for the other field.
I've tried various approaches, including object().noUnknown() and defining custom validation functions, but neither approach resolves the issue.
How can I ensure that Yup validates both baseMonth targetMonth and matrix independently, considering they share the same object type, and shows errors for all fields simultaneously if they fail validation?
